How to perform a Yes/No Read-Host and Timeout in Powershell
So I want to have a Read-Host (or anything else that is capable of reading input) and a Timeout.
For example:
The user is asked if he wants to continue the script.
If he types "Yes" it will continue.
If he types "No" the script will end
If no input is made in 20 seconds, the script will continue.
Thanks for your help!
Already tried:
$sleepSeconds = 10
$timeout = New-TimeSpan -Seconds $sleepSeconds
 $stopWatch = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()


while ($stopWatch.Elapsed -lt $timeout)
{
     if ($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable) 
    {
        $keyPressed = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho, IncludeKeyUp, IncludeKeyDown")
        Write-Host "Abbruch"
        if ($keyPressed.KeyDown -eq "True") { break }           
    } 
}

